# Magnify search box similar to that on Apple.com

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you go to http://apple.com and click in the search box, you'll notice it grows/magnifies `onfocus`, and `onblur` it collapses back to it's original state.

I'm wondering if there's a jquery plugin or similar to do this job easily.

I don't want to use the JS that's on the Apple website since it's not fully cross browser. I also don't have time to roll my own. If there's nothing prebuilt, that's ok, but if anyone knows of anything pre-made, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Note: works in webkit browsers only.

Comment: Yes I see that the one on Apple's website only works with FireFox, Safari, and Chrome. I'm looking for something a little more cross browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search box like at apple.com without JS:
http://www.kvadracom.com/en-projects-blog.html#1

Comment: Great no JavaScript solution

Answer (score 1):

It's been there a while, here's another SO post:

[Mimic apple.com globalsearch input field with HTML and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494533/mimic-apple-com-globalsearch-input-field-with-html-and-css)

Comment: Yes I did see this question. The answer shows the JS for the Apple website, which unfortunately only works in FireFox, Safari, and Chrome. I'm looking for something a little more cross browser.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this.It is working in IE,firfox,chrome.I didnt check for others

```
$('input').focus(function() {
         $(this).css({'width': '50px'});
});

$('input').blur(function() {
         $(this).css({'width': '100px'});
 });
```

Similarly you could use background-color property to toggle between color

### ----- Edit by OP ---

I marked this as answer, however I did modify it to be a lot more like the Apple website.

```
$('input').focus(function() {
         $(this).animate({width: 150}, 'slow');
});

$('input').blur(function() {
         $(this).animate({width: 100}, 'slow');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article I think it can help you to certain extent.....the search box doesn't get focus when clicked but it's size is increased......http://www.bloggermint.com/2011/06/css3-search-box-inspired-by-apple-com/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.